Which Firebase services do I need to generate random numbers on server side?
I need to create random number on server side and return this value to some clients on different platforms. Maybe one of Firebase Services do I need?
I use Flutter, if this is important.
I understand that I can create my own server and use hosting, so maybe Firebase can help me?

While you can probably do this server side, why? Why not just generate the number on a device and upload it to the Firebase? All of the clients that are watching that document will receive the random number.

Not sure why you need to create a random number on server side when you have Random class in  dart:math.
If you really want to do this in Firebase you can create a Cloud Function in Firebase.

Thanks, I need to create random value on server side, becoause after this a need to give this value lots of clients. I realize concept of game "SpinTheBottle", so i need to get random user from the "table" (server).

Nice. If you found it helpful, upvote or mark tas right answer.
